# Looking for an old ghost movie from 80s-90s

Tags: story-identification, movie, ghost

It was a ghost movie that was based on a book of the same or similar name. set in The Rocks, NSW and watched it on YouTube in around 2010. The opening scene was a playground where a little girl ghost appeared and scared these kids and told her life. I also think she was blue? or her name was Betty or something not rlly sure. Definitely a B there somewhere. I also remember a factory scene and a boyfriend. Something about her wanting an education also.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this live-action or animated?  Was it a full-length movie or a short?

Answer (score 9):

This is almost certainly the Australian film [Playing Beatie Bow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_Beatie_Bow_(film)) (1986), based on the [book of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_Beatie_Bow) by Ruth Park.

It was set, and filmed, in The Rocks, NSW. The film is still on YouTube, and you'll see the opening scene is indeed a playground with a ghost.